# Ruby on Rails architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, rack

I am pretty new to ruby on rails. I have setup an `Apache` server which directs requests to `Phusion Passenger`, `Passenger` invokes corresponding controller and gets the job done.
When is rack module(`config.ru`) called? Will it be called for each request Apache sends to Passenger? Could I get a detailed flow of events that happen between `Apache` and `Passenger`?

Answer (score 0):

`config.ru`is loaded when the rack server (passenger in this case) starts. What exactly happens during a request really depends on your setup. But the basic flow is like this:

When a request comes in to Apache, it will first try to serve the file from the `public/` directory of your app. If this fails, Passenger will forward the request to your app which then processes the request and hands the response back to Passenger. Passenger in turn then hands the response back to Apache which will transmit it to the client.